# ASP.NET vbhtml with razor syntax gives wrong answer for DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek?

Tags: asp.net, razor, webmatrix

```
<!-- Multi-statement block --> 
@Code
dim greeting = "Welcome to our site!" 
dim weekDay = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek 
dim greetingMessage = greeting & " Here in Huston it is: " & weekDay
End Code

<p>The greeting is: @greetingMessage</p>
```

week day shows '4' which is the current month but when used alone without '&' like this

```
dim greetingMessage = weekDay
```

OR

```
<p>@DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek</p>
```

then it shows the correct weekday.

Comment: Can you try & (weekDay)?

Comment: It will always returns 0-6 value or 1-7

Comment: What Actually you want to display?

Comment: You will get value as 0-6, Sunday as 0 ,... and Saturday as 6, so today is Thursday and you should get value as 4 thats correct

Comment: it gives 'Thursday' when used alone without '&' tag as I've mentioned in the question and the same code works fine with vshtml with + sign(c#). Only in vbhtml it returns a number when used with '&'.

Comment: plz check this link and it shows Thursday but when i try the same code with WebMatrix it gives the integer value instead of string value: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showfile_vb.asp?filename=try_razor_vb_001

Comment: use dim weekDay = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString()

Actually this is enum, so once you use .ToString() it will return the string name

Comment: Yes, It works !! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the ways are same. In the first scenario, 4 is not the month. It is the number for Thursday. Use weekDay.ToString().

```
 <!-- Multi-statement block -->
    @Code
        Dim greeting = "Welcome to our site!"
        Dim weekDay = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek
        Dim greetingMessage = greeting & " Here in Huston it is: " & weekDay.ToString()
    End Code
```

Comment: Tried but same result. I am learner and using WebMatrix. The code 'DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek' works fine when typed alone without '&' and the same code works fine in vshtml. The problem occur for only vbhtml

Comment: Use weekDay.ToString(). I tried it in vbhtml only. It is working fine

Comment: Yeah, it works now :) Thanks !! but, do u have any idea why it returns integer value? it supposed to give string value. same code returns string value in cshtml and even in vbhtml when used alone without '&' sign.

Comment: The members of the DayOfWeek enumeration are not localized. To return the localized name of the day of the week, we have to convert to string.